# jQuery calculation (getting a NaN, but only when the number is over 1000)

Tags: jquery

Hear me out please, this is a weird error I have encountered. Let's say `discountValue = 5` and `grandTotal = 10`, the `discountShow` will properly output and format the result. But if the `grandTotal` is `greater` than `999`, `discountShow` will output a `NaN`

```
function discount_compute() {
  var discountValue = parseFloat($('#discount').val().replace(',', '.'));
  var discountTotal = grandTotal * (1 - (discountValue / 100));
  var discountShow = numeral(discountTotal.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00'); 
  $('.net-total-discount').html(discountShow + " &euro;");
  }
```

Comment: Not really enough information.  Where are you getting grandTotal from? Are you sure it doesn't have a comma in it?  What is the function "numeral"?

Comment: `parseFloat()` is probably giving the NaN. Firstly, separate the statements out into separate lines; ie get the value from the field, then call `parseFloat()` on it in a separate line of code. That will make it easier to debug because you can use the browser's dev tools to see what value you're passing into `parseFloat()`.

Comment: Post your `numeral` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

Change `format('0,0.00');` to `format('0,0.[00]');`

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/8kea3qj8/3/)**

```js
function discount_compute() {
  var grandTotal = 10;
  var discountValue = 5;
  var discountTotal = grandTotal * (1 - (discountValue / 100));
  var discountShow = discountTotal.toFixed(2)
  var discountShow = numeral(discountTotal.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.[00]'); 
  document.write(discountShow + " &euro;");
}
discount_compute();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
```